# Python os.walk always attaches root

Tags: python, root, os.walk

For my study I'm busy with a project in Python.

I'm quite stuck atm on something very odd..

Here's the code I'm running (well a small part of the code but it also produces the same error):

```
import os

path_input = raw_input('Give path to check for documents(e.g. /Users/Frank/Desktop): ')
if os.path.isdir(path_input):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_input):
        for file in dirs:
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() in ('.docx', '.pdf', '.doc', '.pptx', '.txt',
                '.ppt', 'xls', 'xlsx'):
                print(os.path.abspath(file))
else:
    print("\nPlease enter a valid path, for example: '/Users/Frank/Documents.'")
```

It reads any file it comes across, it finds in the os.walk, but whenever when `print(os.path.abspath(file))` part comes, it always attached my root folder of where the script is stored.

I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.

**Update(added example of output):**

```
/Users/Username/Dropbox/Test/Python/version5.txt
/Users/Username/Dropbox/Test/Python/version6.txt
/Users/Username/Dropbox/Test/Python/version7.txt
```

As you can see, it always says "/Users/Username/Dropbox/Test/Python/"
Which is the same location as the python script it stored while the .txt files are stored in another location.

Comment: Can you show some example incorrect output? It's not clear what the problem is. "Attached my root folder" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Added example of output.

Comment: What do you *want* the output to be instead?

Comment: Well, I'd like it to show the files actually absolute path, instead of the path where the python script is stored.

Comment: Well, I'm not looking for any specific files, I want all the files that end with the extension that I look for.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am talking about

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath but that's not what abspath is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you call `os.walk`, it returns the **root**, a list of **directories**, and a list of **files**.  Although your program reads like correct English, it's not doing what you want it to do in Python.  The line `for file in dirs` is *not* looking at all the files in the directories; it is just looping over all the subfolders of `root`.  What I think you really want is to loop over `files` instead:

```
import os

path_input = raw_input('Give path to check for documents(e.g. /Users/Frank/Desktop): ')
if os.path.isdir(path_input):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_input):
        ### iterate over files instead of dirs
        for file in files:
            # The full file path needs to be made by joining with root.
            fullfile = os.path.join(root, file)
            if os.path.splitext(fullfile)[1].lower() in ('.docx', '.pdf', '.doc', '.pptx', '.txt',
                '.ppt', 'xls', 'xlsx'):
                print(os.path.abspath(fullfile))
else:
    print("\nPlease enter a valid path, for example: '/Users/Frank/Documents.'")
```

Comment: I had that before, still the same problem. It does correctly loop through all the files. But when I print it's absolute path + filename is always show the folder in which the python script is stored. See OP, I attached an example of the output.

Comment: @Nerotix did you have the line `fullfile = os.path.join(root, file)` and print `abspath(fullfile)`?  I updated my answer to do that. Remeber that files is a list of **file names** and not **file paths**.  To get the full path you have to join the root with the name.

Comment: Will try, gimme a few mins. Thanks!

Comment: @Nerotix Are you sure you copied and pasted the code exactly?  Or that you're giving the right path to `raw_input`?  I just tested it and it does work...

Comment: And for extra info, that path is the root location of the Python script and definitely not the location of the files it shows.

Comment: I apologise dear sir ;) I forgot to add the fullfile to the print object. Thanks a ton dude! Been stuck on it for 2 hours lol.

Comment: Glad to help @Nerotix!  Could you reverse the downvote please: :-)  maybe even upvote and accept the answer?

Comment: I didn't do that down vote.. :o I did update anyways and selected it as answer. Thanks again kind, sir!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.endswith`to find your matching files, you also need to search files not dirs and join to the root directory:

```
import os

ends = ('.docx', '.pdf', '.doc', '.pptx', '.txt','.ppt', 'xls', 'xlsx')
path_input =  raw_input('Give path to check for documents(e.g. /Users/Frank/Desktop): ')
if os.path.isdir(path_input):
     files = (os.path.abspath(f) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_input)
              for f in files if f.endswith(ends))
    for f in files:
        print(f)
else:
    print("\nPlease enter a valid path, for example: '/Users/Frank/Documents.'")
```

Comment: I like using `str.endswith`, but the nested comprehension is not easy to understand at a glance.  If it's going to be more than one like it should usually just be a for loop, IMHO.

Comment: @CodyPiersall, the OP may want to store the lines in a list, lazily evaluate or pass them to a function, a generator expression gives them the Option to do any of those

Comment: True, but the readable way would still be to have an _actual_ function that `yield`s the files.